# Array of object converted to string

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i'm using formidable to parse my form.

I'm not familiar with formidable so i don't know why my array of object is converted to "String".

What i send to the server using reactjs :

```
[{"size":"M","stock":"6"},{"size":"L","stock":"6"}]
```

What i get in the server :

```
'[{"size":"M","stock":"6"},{"size":"L","stock":"6"}]'
```

Without JSON.stringify(arrayOfStocks) i get :

```
'[object Object],[object Object]'
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "send"? Where are you sending it, and where are you seeing the string printed?

Comment: if you pass directly array or an object into JSX you will get this error. can you specify how you are trying to show so can give the solutions?

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify([{"size":"M","stock":"6"},{"size":"L","stock":"6"}])` in the console, then try `JSON.parse('[{"size":"M","stock":"6"},{"size":"L","stock":"6"}]')`. See the difference.

Comment: HOW do you send it? You need to show more code

Comment: @DrewReese solved , forgot to parse in the server side thank u

Comment: @DrewReese if you want to give me an answer so i can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the console try

```
JSON.stringify([{"size":"M","stock":"6"},{"size":"L","stock":"6"}])
```

Then try

```
JSON.parse('[{"size":"M","stock":"6"},{"size":"L","stock":"6"}]')
```

If you are sending the serialized (stringified) array then you should parse it on the other end.

Answer (score -1):

try using a state to hold your data, and update its content , you will find your array saved in the state

```
const [data,setData] = useState([]);
```

onChange event of your inputs ::: `onChange={()=>{data.push({"size":"M","stock":"6"})}`